# How to make use of an external Js file in .net core 2.1 and Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

I am new to Angular 6 and .Net Core 2.1. I've created a some application but now I need to make use of jquery events. I have installed Jquery packages to node_modules as well.

Could anyone please help me!! 
Thanks in advance

[image]

Even in the angular-cli.json file, I've added the jquery files and my custom js file.
But still not working.
Below are my configuration and code

[image]

[image]

[image]

Solution Structure
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will find here an example [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176)

I would recommend to keep JQuery out of your Angular project. You have to understand how Angular 2+ works and you will see that there is no need for JQuery.
With JQuery you were selecting an element in the page and modify it but with Angular the UI changes based on a model property. It is another way of thinking about the UI.

You can read more about the differences between the two here [link](https://www.educba.com/angular-vs-jquery/). I also tried to use JQuery when I began using Angular because of my previous experience but I learned that was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jQuery u will need to put the files in the wwwroot folder. You can link it from there.

[image: solution explorer vivew]
[image: linking the script in the cshtml file]